# struct stack error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c

Code (test.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct stack {
    double a[100];
    int maxSize = 100;
};
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
gcc -Wall -o "test" "test.c"
```

Errors:

```
gcc -Wall -o "test" "test.c" (in directory: /home/amey)
test.c:4:17: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
     int maxSize = 100;
                 ^
Compilation failed.
```

Why is this not compiling?

Comment: In the C language, you cannot assign initial values to the members of the structure.

Comment: You cannot assign a value in a struct declaration.

Comment: Because it is illegal in C. You cannot assign a value to struct fields in its declaration.

Comment: Okay, then what should I do?

Comment: Just use `int maxSize` and initialize it when needed

Comment: I want to have a maxSize and a top=-1 variable.

Comment: Why do you want to have that in the struct declaration?

Comment: @AmeyBhavsar After you create a structure object, initialize it. Instead of assigning values directly when defining the structure.

Comment: @Gerhardh so that I can perform pop, push operations

Comment: @ZhuSong how to initialize those variables, for example when I want to create a stack variable?

Comment: That does not answer my question. Why not just initialize the variables with proper values? Why put it in struct declaration?

Comment: `struct stack s; s.maxSize = 100` Perform similar operations at initialization.

Comment: @Gerhardh using a constructor?

Comment: There is no concept of "constructor" in C. You have to create an `init` function which takes a struct variable and assigns initial values.

Comment: C does not have constructors. C has initializers that you can use when defining variables: `struct stack mystack = {.maxSize = 100};`

Comment: @ZhuSong is it not possible to have default values for them?

Comment: Apart from what has already been commented: it doesn't make much sense to have a _variable_ `maxSize ` because the size of `a` is fixed to 100 anyway. The proper way would be `#define MAXSIZE 100`, and then `double a[MAXSIZE];` and drop `int maxSize` alltogether.

Comment: In C language, yes.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you @ZhuSong

Comment: @AmeyBhavsar BTW `gcc -Wall -o test test.c` is good enough, you don't need to put the filenames between `""`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, those were just the default IDE commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare default values in a struct declaration in C. This is simply not allowed in the C language.

What you can do is this:

```
...
int main()
{
  struct stack mystack;
  mystack.maxSize = 100;
  ...
```

or

```
...
int main()
{
  struct stack mystack = {.maxSize = 100};
  ...
```

But anyway it doesn't make much sense to have a variable `maxSize` because the size of `a` is fixed to 100 anyway. The proper way would be a `#define MAXSIZE 100` or `const int MAXSIZE = 1000;`, and then declare `double a[MAXSIZE];` and drop the field `maxSize` alltogether.

That being said, you probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define MAXSTACKSIZE 100
// or 
// const int MAXSIZE = 100;
 
struct stack {
    double stack[MAXSTACKSIZE];
    int stackpointer;
};
 
void InitializeStack(struct stack *thestack)
{
  thestack->stackpointer = 0;
}
 
void push(struct stack *thestack, double value)
{
   // to be written (3-4 lines including error checking)
}
 
double pop(struct stack *thestack)
{
   // to be written (3-4 lines including error checking)
}
 
int main() {
    struct stack mystack;
    InitializeStack(&mystack);
    push(&mystack, 1.234);
    printf("%f\n", pop(&mystack));   // output should be 1.234
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @thebusybee this has been extensively dealt with in the comments.

Comment: Not at all. I think this is clearly a syntax error, but you don't explain it.

Comment: @thebusybee answer enhanced.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. This is exactly how I did it.